# Replace null values with N/A in a spark dataframe

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to replace the null values with N/A. I have tried with following code but none of them works:

```
df.withColumn("series_name", when($"series_name") === null,"n/a")
.otherwise($series_name)
```

and

```
df.withColumn("series_name", when(col("series_name") === null,"n/a")
```

what am I missing?

```
    +--------------------+
    |         series_name|
    +--------------------+
    |Families of the M...|
    |                null|
    |      Ridiculousness|
    |                null|
    |                null|
    +--------------------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also use the .fillna() method:

```py
df.fillna('N/A', subset=['series_name'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use `coalesce`.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

df.withColumn('series_name', f.expr("coalesce(series_name, 'n/a')"))
```

Comment: What does coalesce do? Do you have a doc reference?

Comment: it is same as ifnull function of mysql.

Comment: yeah, not a fan of sql :) The strange thing is that it is the same word as the operation that reduce partition number of a dataset. That's a little confusing

Comment: it is a spark function and you can use it like col or lit. I know that is the same name with partition collector :)